# Cant Apply New Id's to field names on loop with jquery

Tags: jquery, loops

I've got a form that is contained within a div that can be duplicated multiple times.

The div is duplicating with the form fields contained within it, however I cant seem to change the ID's of the fields within each div.

```
$(".clonedInput").each(function(i){
    var _item_counter = i;
    var $this = $(this);

    $(".clonedInput div.form-group .pagination-calculator-field").each(function(i){                        
        $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('data-id') + '-' + _item_counter);
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

I'm trying to rename each field with the count of which div it resides in when created dynamically. I can see it logs to the console correctly. however when on the page it doesn't apply the correct ID's.

Is there something I'm not doing right ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure, but can you write function(this) instead function(i) in your code

Comment: since i is not incremented it resides the same id for each element and thus having problem as if the id should be unique.... so try using class instead of id and should work....